# Java XML Document XPath with Disable Escaping

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Currently, I need to get the element of XML without escaping.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
      <Header>H001</Header>
      <Body>
            <Item>ABC&amp;amp;ABC&amp;quot;</Item>
      </Body>
</Message>
```

I need to get the value of "Item" element via XPath. 
However, it is escaped automatically.

My Result = `ABC&amp;ABC&quot;`

Expected = `ABC&amp;amp;ABC&amp;quot;`

How can I get the expected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put content surrounded by `CDATA`.

**Note:** **Charater data (CDATA) will tell the parser to send the text as regular text (no markup) without parsing.**

For example :

**abc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Messages>
    <Message>
        <Header>H001</Header>
        <Body>
            <Item><![CDATA[ABC&amp;&amp;ABC&amp;quot;]]></Item>
        </Body>
    </Message>
</Messages>
```

Java code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.xml");
        Document doc = builder.parse(input);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("Message");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
                node = children.item(j);
                System.out.println(node.getTextContent().trim());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Output :

```
H001

ABC&amp;&amp;ABC&amp;quot;
```

Comment: Hi Anish, Yes. I able to get what I need with adding CDATA. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

XPath will always return the values of nodes that result from XML parsing. The string value of the Item element in your XML, after parsing, is `ABC&amp;ABC&quot;`, so that's what XPath gives you. If you want `ABC&amp;amp;ABC&amp;quot;` then you will have to reverse the action of the XML parser - this is known as serialization. Parsing "unescapes" entity and character references (it turns `&amp;` into `&`). Serialization escapes special characters such as "&" (it turns `&` into `&amp;`).

Comment: Hi Michael, noted on this. I also notice that the XMLParser that I run during w3c Document generation has already escaped this character. I able to get this value by replacing the & to another value before parse it. Thanks